# Button click of a Card component does not work in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use a [Card](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards) component of Vuetify, and in the actions you can create buttons.

But I noticed clicks on such buttons do not work ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/begueradj/pen/WgYONW)):

```
<v-card-actions>
    <v-btn flat color="orange" @click="alert(888)">Share</v-btn>
    <v-btn flat color="orange">Explore</v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

I tried with [`native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Listening-for-Native-Events-on-Components-with-v-on-changed) (`@click.native="alert(888)"`) but the click does not work in that case either.

What am I missing?

Comment: They "work". Do you read errors?

Comment: @BillalBegueradj, looks like your codepen at the link you provided has been updated to include my solution, which is maybe confusing Traxo

Comment: @thanksd No, sorry, I am not confused at all. There were self-descriptive errors in the original codepen. Here is the original: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJMzWz And errors onclick: `Property or method "alert" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` also `alert is not a function`

Comment: @Traxo Indeed, you are absolutely right ... your feedback is always accurate and useful, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inline handler for the click event is scoped to the Vue instance, not the `window`. So Vue is looking for an `alert` method on your component and not finding one.

---

Simply add a method to your component to call `alert`:

```
methods: {
  onClick() {
    alert(888);
  }
}
```

And then use that as the click handler instead:

```
<v-btn flat color="orange" @click="onClick">Share</v-btn>
```

---

[Here's a working version of your codepen example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJXLxO)